# How do I automate deployment of Java non web based application

Tags: windows, unix, deployment, jenkins, automation

- **My Application**: Java based server and client application.
- **Need**: To automate the deployment process in UAT and PROD in both windows and unix environemnt.
- **Present State**: Manual steps given to support team to follow and deploy.
- **Main steps involved in deployment on UNIX or WINDOWS** : 1) download the artifact from hudson 2) stop the process 3) unzip the application 4) start the process

**What I am looking for:**

-**Suggestions** to automate the deployment. Tools or product.

-**Details** or links to documentation so that I can understand how that particular tool or product will solve my issue.

Comment: Client app, use JavaWebStart.

Comment: For the server side, have you considered using a deployment tool such as [kwatee](http://kwatee.net)

Answer (score 0):

- Write batch/bash script and trigger it with parameters, from Jenkins.
- The script will download the artifacts
- Stop process
- Unzip artifacts
- Start process